# Arch Linux, 4K Display, i3wm + Xorg, Some icons too small, but others normal

Tags: arch-linux, icons, high-dpi, i3-window-manager

I am currently running Arch (btw) with i3wm on a Dell XPS 13 Plus 9320 and I am running into some issues with the 3840x2400 pixel display. As shown in the screenshot below, some of my icons correctly scale with the screen, but some are so small they are barely readable. For example, most icons are the correct size in Thunar but some, such as the back and home buttons in the top right corner, appear far smaller than intended.

[image: Thunar UI]

Another example is GIMP, where once again, some icons appear the correct size but others like the checkboxes are far too small.

[image: GIMP UI]

I have set my DPI in `~/.Xresources` using `xft.dpi = 288`, which let most applications scale correctly. Additionally I am using the Papirus-Dark.HiDPI icon theme and also set Toolbar Icon Size to "Large toolbar icon", although the latter seemed to have no effect. Both icon theme and size were changed through `lxappearance`.

I would love to know if there is a blanket fix to this that I am missing, as I would rather not individually set configs for every application that has issues.